# bash validating user name with regex

Tags: regex, bash, validation

from the useradd man page I should be able to verify if a filed red from a file is a valid username with:

```
if [ $1 =~ [a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*[$]? ]; then
```

white space is not allowed, but is not detected, first character is limited to a-z and underscore but again, it did not detected correctly, also Fedora has a limit of 16 char.
So modified it to something like that:

```
GroupeEtUsagerValide() {
    if [ ${#1} -gt 16 ];then
        return 1
        elif [[ $1 =~ ^[[:lower:]_][[:lower:][:digit:]_-]{2,15} ]]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
    fi 
}
```

white space was detected, but not anymore, I must have change something and can't find it
This is a function $1 is a value read from a file

Comment: What's with the `[$]?`? I don't believe a trailing literal `$` is valid. Perhaps you didn't mean for it to be literal?

Comment: ...indeed, it's explicitly not required by POSIX, which specifies that the portable filename character set is the minimum space required to be valid for usernames; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_276

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- Regex matching (using ERE syntax) is available only in `[[ ]]`, not `[ ]` (as used in your first code sample).
- The default return value of a function is that of the last command in it. Thus the `if` is entirely unneeded.
- If you don't anchor your regex explicitly, with `^` at the beginning **and** `$` at the end, it won't be anchored at all. Your current code doesn't have an anchor at the end, so it would accept anything with at least three valid characters even if those characters are followed by a space.

---

```
isValidUsername() {
  local re='^[[:lower:]_][[:lower:][:digit:]_-]{2,15}$'
  (( ${#1} > 16 )) && return 1
  [[ $1 =~ $re ]] # return value of this comparison is used for the function
}
```

To use this:

```
testValidUsername() {
  if isValidUsername "$1"; then
    echo "$1 is a valid username"
  else
    echo "$1 is not a valid username"
  fi
}

testValidUsername abcdefg
testValidUsername 1234567
testValidUsername a123456
testValidUsername 012345678901234567890
```

...and output, as expected:

```
abcdefg is a valid username
1234567 is not a valid username
a123456 is a valid username
012345678901234567890 is not a valid username
```

Comment: So (( ${#1} > 16 )) will give you what a true value if the length is greater than 16 ?  but I am not sure what is going on when you add && return 1, my guess is that if it the left portion is true and the right portion will always evaluate to true, doing an && wil return a value of 1?

Comment: I have modified my code and tried Charles Duffy's code with the same result. invalid name are not detected. Do not know how to format texte here , I have put some echo to see what is going on, in this example, I have vOisin and it should have been detected as invalid, but is is not Value received by function: vOisin
We are sending this username:  vOisin return value 0 value received by function: vOisin
We are sending this username:  vOisin return value 0

Comment: I also have a username mo jo and that is definitly invalid, there should be no white sapce and this one is not detected has well

Comment: OK, the regular expression is good, something is happening when I use a function, this is strange because if I echo the value received, everything look OK

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the function when reproducing the problem? For instance, inside the function text, `$1` refers to the first argument passed *to the function*, not the first argument to the script; thus, if you weren't passing the script argument through to the function, that would be one possible implementation.

Comment: Sorry for not replying, (I think it is pretty bad when peoples are trying to help you and you don't reply). I solved the problem  late at night and was exhausted, I submitted my work and went on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

The Regular Expression for Username Validation:

```bash
^[[:alpha:][:digit:]_-]{3,15}$
```

*Usernames between 3 and 15 characters (Uppercase or lowercase letters with digits and the symbols: `-` and `_` are allowed.)*

##### Usage:

```
username="John"
if [[ "$username" =~ ^[[:alpha:][:digit:]_-]{3,15}$ ]]; then
  echo "Username is valid"
fi
```

See Ubuntu [Regex Basics](https://ubuntu.com/blog/regex-basics) blog to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

I was pretty close at the beginning, the man page was right, I was just missing the anchors.

```
if [[ $usager =~ ^[[:lower:]_][[:lower:][:digit:]_-]*[$]?$ ]]; then
```

Comment: This thing is really driving me crazy, I start a new script with only the need code with no function and everything was working fine, I then put the code in a function and called it and it is still working and I do not see any difference BTW the 2 scripts, must be a newbie error that I cannot see.